# If $\sec x=\frac{a}{b}$, find the exact value of $\cot x-\frac1{\sin x}$, for positive $a$ and $b$, and for $x\in(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $\sec(x) = \frac{a}{b}$, find the exact value of
> $$\cot(x) - \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$$ and $a$, $b$ are positive real values and $x\in(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi)$

- I know that $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}, $ so:  $\cos(x) = \frac{b}{a}$
- I used the right angled triangle to find the third side, which is $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$
- I used reciprocal functions of $\tan$ and $\sin$ to obtain the values:

$cosec(x) = \frac{a}{(\sqrt{a^2-b^2})}$ and $\cot(x) = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$

and finally getting $\frac{(b-a)}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$ as my answer. But that is not correct.
The correct answer is: $\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a+b}$. Now I am wondering how.

Comment: Check the signs in the 4th quadrant, and rationalize your denominator.

Comment: Cosecant is negative, since $ \ a \ $ is positive, but $ \ \sin x \ $ is negative in the fourth quadrant.

Comment: $cosec(x) = - \frac{a}{(\sqrt{a^2-b^2})}$ given it is fourth quadrant. Finally multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remember, when using a right-angled triangle to determine
  trigonometric values, we are actually ***just*** determining their
  *absolute* values (i.e., dropping any negative sign).

  This is evidenced by the fact that the process evaluates ratios of triangle *lengths*, each of which is expressed as a *nonnegative* value in the form $\sqrt{u^2\pm v^2}.$

In the given example, since $x$ is located in the fourth quadrant, $\operatorname{cosec}x$ must be negative and so equals $\displaystyle\mathbf-\left(\frac a{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right)$ rather than $\displaystyle\frac a{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos x=\frac ba$$

$$\frac 1{\sin x}=\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}}=\frac a{\sqrt {a^2-b^2}}$$

$$\cot (x) =\frac {\cos x}{\sin x}=\frac{\frac ba}{\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}a}=\frac b{\sqrt {a^2-b^2}}$$

$\Rightarrow$ $$\cot (x)-\frac 1{\sin x}=\frac {a-b}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$

Multiplying numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)}$ we get:

$$\cot (x)-\frac 1{\sin x}=\frac {\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a+b}$$